# Trackpad and battery on stop working at same time

Tags: windows-7, battery, touchpad

- Gateway E-475M G
- Windows 7 Professional SP1
- Synaptics TouchPad 15.2.20.0
- Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery 6.1.7600.16385

It seems that when my battery stops working correctly, my touchpad will also act erratically.

Specifically, the computer will charge for a few seconds, then stop charging for another few seconds. This will continue for some time. But if I close the lid, the charging LED will stay lit. As for the touchpad, it'll click or highlight things at random when I can get it to move.

As a test, I stopped charging my computer. Now  it seems my touchpad is working fine.

I've tried to reinstall both the battery and touchpad drivers. I've also started the computer in safe mode, but that didn't help either.

Edit:

I've now tried booting my computer with an Ubuntu live cd, and the charging problem persists. So, it now seems my computer can only charge continuously as long as it's turned off or sleeping.

Comment: Failing batteries can do some strange things. How old is the battery?  Have you tried a new one?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another battery I can test. It seemed to me though, that it might be a software issue since the computer can apparently charge correctly if it's turned off or in sleep mode.

Comment: Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode?  How about when you boot to another OS?

Comment: The touchpad and battery still have issues in Safe Mode. I will have to burn a live CD and see if I still have those issues.